# The augment() function in the broom package is throwing up an error warning of new levels, when I run it against the training data set

Tags: r, tidymodels, recipe, broom

```
rf_spec<-rand_forest(mtry =7 ) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", importance = 'permutation') %>%
  set_mode("classification")

rf_fit <- fit(rf_spec, class_outcome ~ ., data = NPS_Data_train)

vip(rf_fit)

augment(rf_fit, new_data = NPS_Data_train) %>%
  conf_mat(truth=class_outcome,estimate=.pred_class)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(mod_terms, new_data, na.action = na.action,  :
> factor FAMILY_TYPE has new levels missing

The above error does not make sense as I'm trying to get the confusion matrix on the training data set used to fit the model, there shouldn't be any new levels missing as it is the training set.

I changed `FAMILY_TYPE` into a factor explicitly, but get the same error

```
NPS_Data_train$FAMILY_TYPE <- as.factor(NPS_Data_train$FAMILY_TYPE)


  FAMILY_TYPE            n
  <fct>              <int>
1 Couple              9028
2 Family             10085
3 Family Plus          810
4 missing             1605
5 Single             21334
6 Single Parent        967
7 Single Parent Plus    98
```

Comment: Can you create a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (a minimal reproducible example) for this? The goal of a reprex is to make it easier for us to recreate your problem so that we can understand it and/or fix it. If you've never heard of a reprex before, you may want to start with the [tidyverse.org help](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/) page.